# What the difference between "parser" and "parserOptions.parser" in ESLint config?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, typescript-eslint, typescript-eslintparser

I has used below preset for TypeScript and Vue for a long time. It works, but I has not understood each option and now going to understand it. First: what the difference between `parser` and `@typescript-eslint/parser`?

```
parser: vue-eslint-parser
parserOptions:
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  sourceType: module
  project: tsconfig.json
  tsconfigRootDir: ./
  extraFileExtensions: [ ".vue" ]

env:
  es6: true
  browser: true
  node: true

plugins:
  - "@typescript-eslint"
  - vue
```

### Experimental data

Without `parser: "vue-eslint-parser"`, we have `[unknown]: Parsing error: Unexpected token :` in TypeScript file in line:

```
(async function executeApplication(): Promise<void> {})()
```

and `Parsing error: Unexpected token <` in `.vue` file in line:

```
<template lang="pug">
```

If we delete or comment out `parserOptions.parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"`,

- `[unknown]: Parsing error: Unexpected token :` will remain.
- `Parsing error: Unexpected token <` will disappear but `Parsing error: Unexpected character '@'` will appear in `@Component export default class extends Vue {` line.

Both `parser` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` are required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`vue-eslint-parser` is the **main parser** to use instead of the default one (`espree`). It will handle .vue SFC files, especially the `<template>` tags.

Within this parser, you have a custom option to specify which parser to use to lint the `<script>` tag in the `.vue` files.

So basically, you're telling eslint to parse `.vue` files with `vue-eslint-parser`, and within this parser, to use `@typescript-eslint/parser` for the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, `parserOptions.parser` means "The separate parser for <script> part?

Comment: This answer helped me for a somewhat different question. I had "@typescript-eslint/parser" as the main parser configured, but was setting up an "overrides" section for a little plain-ol' JavaScript. This is the first place that I found out the default parser was "espree", so now I know what to set the override "parser" to without explicitly undoing all of the cases where I'd turned off a basic ESLint rule to override it with a TypeScript-specific rule.